# L2S System.DateTime has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My Data Service is has method of type IQueryable and my controller is trying to convert the date time but I am getting this error. Any help would me great.

Error

```
Method 'System.String ToCommonDateString(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

data Service

```
    public IQueryable<TemplatesJoinAgent> GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId(Guid? agentKey, Guid? diseaseId)
            {
                //Common part
                var TemplatesJoinAgent = (from t in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Template>().Get(t => t.IsCurrentVersion && t.Status == (short)TemplateMode.Published)
                                          join r in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Regimen>().Get() on t.Id equals r.TemplateId
                                          join rp in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenPart>().Get() on r.Id equals rp.RegimenId
                                          join re in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenEntry>().Get() on rp.Id equals re.RegimenPartId
                                          join a in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Agent>().Get() on re.AgentVersionKey equals a.VersionKey
                                          select new TemplatesJoinAgent
                                          {
                                              TemplateId = t.TemplateId,
                                              TemplateTitle = t.Title,
                                              GroupTitle = t.GroupTitle,
                                              GuideLineTitle = t.GuideLineTitle,
                                              ExternalDiseaseId = t.ExternalDiseaseId,
                                              DiseaseName = t.DiseaseName,
                                              VersionKey = t.VersionKey,
                                              AgentRxNormTallMan = a.RxNormTallMan,
                                              AgentNccnTallMan = a.NccnTallMan,
                                              AgentName = a.Name,
                                              AgentVersionKey = a.VersionKey,
                                              Added = t.Added,
                                              Modified = t.Modified,
                                              Indication = t.Indications,
    
    
                                          });
    
                TemplatesJoinAgent = TemplatesJoinAgent.Distinct();
    
                return TemplatesJoin
}
```

controller

```
 PublishedDate = (t.Modified ?? t.Added).ToCommonDateString(),


public static string ToCommonDateString(this DateTime? d)
{
    return (d.HasValue ? d.Value.ToCommonDateString() : "N/A");
}
```

Comment: You may need to get the raw data first then add `PublishedDate` separately, but you don;t show enough code to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine does not know how to translate your custom function to SQL. The simplest way to get around that is to add an `AsEnumerable()` before your projection that uses the custom function. That changes the context from SQL to in-memory and allows custom functions.

The risk is that you want to make sure you have executed as many of your filters as you can *before* calling `AsEnumerable()`, otherwise you'll be pulling back more data than you need and filtering in-memory. Of course, if your *filters* require custom functions then you'll either have to accept that or change your filter to be SQL-compatible.

Comment: So this would mean that view data like formatting a Date time would be added to the data service?

Comment: No, formatting can still stay in the view. IS this function called from the view?

Comment: If your controller is exposing an `IQueryable<T>` to the view then it may just be as simple as changing the type to `IEnumerable<T>` so you're not limited in what transformations you can do in your view.